# Ion-Tab-bar is completly gone after position absolute

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic-framework

i want my content of my ionic component to run below my tabbar, but i can't make this black bar transparent using css. another color is possible. if i set the position to absolute my tabbar is gone, and the conent stretches across the whole page of my component, how can i make my tabbar transparent above my component, and the content continue to run below it?

tabs.page.html:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">

    <ion-tab-button tab="favoriten">
      <ion-icon name="bookmarks-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="startseite">
      <ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="me">
      <ion-icon name="person-outline"></ion-icon>
    </ion-tab-button>

  </ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>
```

tabs.page.css

```
ion-tab-bar{
  //position: absolute !important;
  --border:none;
  --background: rgba(255,255,255,5);
  margin: 16px 20px;
  border-radius: 14px;
  box-shadow:
  0px 3px 6px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.04),
  0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
}
```

[image]